# Configure CPU for Viewport and GPU for render

Tags: rendering

I have an AMD Ryzen 2200G and just started my first Blender tutorial (donut).  In Viewport mode, CPU is faster, but for Render the integrated GPU is faster.  How can I configure Blender to have Viewport with my CPU and Render with my GPU?

Comment: Please add a screenshot with the settings you used for both cases, to understand what you tried.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/fR5qMrd   In Viewport Shading mode and the render engine Cycles + GPU is selected, my PC moves becomes very slow.  Every time I zoom takes several minutes to render in real time the image, so It takes a lot of time to edit or sculpt.